# moving whatsapp data from Android 4 to Android 13

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 4.2-jelly-bean, data-transfer, device-migration

As you probably know (https://faq.whatsapp.com/1150261202542208), Whatsapp is not going to support Android 4 phones from 23rd of October this year; the minimum supported Android version will be 5.0

I want to move and merge all my conversations and files from my old Android phone to my newer one (they both have been used with the same phone number).

Unfortunately, I don't have any Google Drive backups on the old phone. Also, I hadn't done any other transfer/migration to my latest phone. I remember that when I'd installed Whatsapp on my newer phone, the application stopped working on the older phone.

Old phone:

- Android 4.2.2 (Samsung Galaxy S Duos GT-S7562)
- Whatsapp 2.21.17.23 (installed from [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/whatsapp-inc/whatsapp/whatsapp-2-21-17-23-release/whatsapp-messenger-2-21-17-23-android-apk-download/?redirected=thank_you_invalid_nonce));
- no Google Drive backups;
- WhatsApp is no longer working (only on the old phone), since I'd installed it on my latest phone;
- at some moment I had to install the Google Play Store 25.2.27-16 for the Whatsapp to continue running (installed from [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-25-2-27-release/google-play-store-25-2-27-16-0-pr-371716608-android-apk-download/?redirected=thank_you_invalid_nonce); more [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/240982/impossible-to-update-whatsapp-due-to-google-play-store-error)); it now displays "Your phone date is inaccurate! Adjust your clock and try again" (but the date displayed is correct)

New phone:

- Whatsapp 2.23.14.79
- Android 13; OneUI 5.1

Thank you very very very much!

Comment: I'd just noticed there are a set of new versions (from 2023) for Android 4.1+ so I will try installing one of them (maybe https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/whatsapp-inc/whatsapp/whatsapp-2-23-7-81-release/)

Comment: Do you still have access to the old phone and its WhatsApp data? If that's the case, then perhaps [WhatsApp doesn't prompt to restore from local storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203523/44325) might help for the new location of WhatsApp data in Android 11+. Also, perhaps copy them to somewhere else (not on the phone) for additional backup plan.

Comment: I'd noticed a latter WhatsApp version is available supporting the Android 4.1+ (thus supporting my Android 4.2.2): https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/whatsapp-inc/whatsapp/whatsapp-2-23-8-72-release/
I had installed it, over 2.23.7.81 which was installed over my previous version

Comment: @AndrewT. my older phone has Android 4.2.2 not 11+